# OSGi and ...? What do I use to controll loading/unloading/reloading of packages?

Tags: java, osgi

I have a large ecosystem of applications and libraries which are currently deployed as a collection of .jars in various application servers (e.g. JBoss AS), and I'm trying to figure out a good set of tools to manage dependencies and life-cycles of the various packages.

I think of the packages as being in one of (at least) three possible states: "unloaded", "pending" and "loaded", loosely defined as follows:

- **Unloaded**: The package is not available at the moment.
- **Pending**: The package itself is available, but not all its dependencies. Therefore, it cannot be used at the moment.
- **Loaded**: The package is available and has all its dependencies satisfied. If it's an application, it can run - if it's a library, it is ready to be used by another package.

(There might also be a few more states, such as "failed" for packages that tried to load but failed for some other reason than that dependencies were not satisfied, etc...)

In the life-cycle of a package, a number of things might cause a package to change state between these three:

- A package with no dependencies is loaded, and goes from *unloaded* to *loaded*.
- A package tries to load, but not all dependencies are satisfied; it goes from *unloaded* to *pending*.
- A package in *pending* state suddenly has all its dependencies satisfied (because some other package went to state *loaded*), and automatically starts loading itself; transition from *pending* to *loaded*.
- A package is unloaded. All loaded packages which depend on the now unloaded package go from *loaded* to *pending*.
- A package is updated to a newer version. All dependent packages are automatically reloaded, to get access to the updated version.

I've started working on using OSGi for defining the dependencies - it rolls well with our build system and produces reliable dependency information. However, if I load the two OSGi bundles `A` and `B` into JBoss, where `B` depends on `A`, and then unload `A`, it seems like `B` happily keeps running. I've understood that there are some hooks that I could use to control this on a low level (framework events), but my spider sense is tingling, saying that *there must be a better way to do this*.

Is there a nice tool/framework/whatever-you-want-to-call-it that will compliment OSGi in these aspects?

Comment: Entering this as a comment rather than an answer because there are many moving parts in the question, which I don't have time to answer in full. However: uninstalling a bundle does not affect dependent bundles *until you do a refresh operation*. The refresh permits OSGi to recalculate the package wirings, at which time the bundle with the missing dependency will become unresolved. The reason for this separate refresh op is that resolving is expensive, so a series of updates/installs/uninstalls should be batched together.

Comment: As for a higher level tool, I recommend you read about the OSGi R5 Repositories and Resolver specifications. You should concentrate on provisioning *groups* of bundles, and the Resolver specification helps you to work out the correct contents of those groups. You can try out the resolver using [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org) version 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare dependancy between modules, the lifecycle is properly managed and the descendant depandancies must be stopped before the top-level module is stopped.

However, stopping a module does nothing more than sending events to the bundle activator and removing references from classloader. Any activities (such as thread or distributed instances) must be manually clean. For example, you must call org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.release(ClassLoader) (if using commons logging) or remove any injected UI-component.

Comment: Will JBoss also re-load the dependant bundles when the dependency is re-installed (perhaps in a newer version)?

Comment: I'm working with a custom server platform built on top of Apache Felix (OSGi implementation).

I suppose JBoss AS is using the "platform" deployment architecture. In this case, the module list depends on a repository. If dependant bundles belongs to the repository, they must be restarted when the platform restart.

Answer (score 4):

In OSGi, existing class loaders will remain active until you *refresh* the framework. So If you unload B (where A depends on B) then A will continue churning happy along untile you refresh. You can refresh the whole framework or only the bundles affected by a given bundle (e.g. refresh B).

The purpose of the refresh is to update/uninstall/install a set of bundles and then apply the changes in an 'atomic' operation.

The old (and most used model) is to get the PackageAdmin service and then call `refreshPackages(null)` on it (osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/… ).
This service is, however, deprecated. So the current way is:

```
 FrameworkWiring fw = context
     .getBundle(0)
     .adapt(FrameworkWiring.class);
 fw.refreshBundles(null);
```

**updated**

Comment: How do you invoke the refresh operation?

Comment: The old (and most used model) is to get the PackageAdmin service and then call refreshPackages(null) on it (http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/PackageAdmin.html#refreshPackages(org.osgi.framework.Bundle[]) ). This service is, however, deprecated. So the new way is to get Bundle 0 (context.getBundle(0)) and then call adapt(FrameworkWiring.class) on it. The resulting FrameworkWiring has a refreshBundles method.